# Why does push to an array with structure work but push with json does not?

Tags: javascript, angular, multidimensional-array

The following code works:

```
private memberOf: PersonCommittee = {
    personcommitteeid: null,
    pkpersonid: null,
    committeeid: null,
    ismember: false,
    isexofficio: false,
    active: true,
  }

private personcomittee[] = PersonCommittee[];

addCommittee() {
  this.memberOf.pkpersonid = this.pkpersonid;
  this.memberOf.committeeid = id;
  this.memberOf.ismember = true;
  this.memberOf.isexofficio = true;
  this.memberOf.active = true;
  this.personcommittees.push( {
      "pkpersonid": this.memberOf.pkpersonid,
      "committeeid": this.memberOf.committeeid,
      "ismember": this.memberOf.ismember,
      "isexofficio": this.memberOf.isexofficio,
      "active": this.memberOf.active
  });
}
```

but this does not:

```
addCommittee() {
  this.memberOf.pkpersonid = this.pkpersonid;
  this.memberOf.committeeid = id;
  this.memberOf.ismember = true;
  this.memberOf.isexofficio = true;
  this.memberOf.active = true;
  this.personcommittees.push(this.memberOf);
}
```

The second code sample pushes the new values to the array, but changes all the values to the new values.

So, for example, if I have one committeeid of 3 and wanted to add another with committeeid of 4, the first example created a personcommittee array showing both, but the second example creates an array with two records with committeeid of 4.

this.memberOf is in the right structure.  In the second example, the structure is pushed to the array, but it over write all previous data.

Why?

Comment: Can you recreate in a stackblitz. I highly doubt that Javascript is failing to push an object to an array.

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: where are you getting id from?

Comment: https://angular-pusherror.stackblitz.io

This is getting an error: Unexpected value 'CommitteeComponent' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.

But the annotation is there and compiles on my local machine.